# How to Redirect One Domain's All Requests (http and https) to Another Domain

Tags: wordpress

I have two domains installed on different serverpilot accounts.
domains are moviesky.in(abc) and moviesky.info (xyz)
So , can u somebody tell me that how can i redirect both http and https (non www & www) request from **abc** to 
**https xyz** (even all other requests of xyz i.e. **https xyz**, xyz and **www version of xyz**)

Should be redirected to https moviesky info. I mean to say that the destination URL from both domains should be only https moviesky info

( When I installed Cloudflare SSL on my site it automatically redirects HTTP request to HTTPS on both domains)

Please somebody help me

Answer (score 0):

In the web root folder of moviesky.in, create a file called .htaccess (If this file already exists, edit/append it).

Place the following in the file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^moviesky.in [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.moviesky.info/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Similarly, in the web root of moviesky.info, add (to .htaccess):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^moviesky.info [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.moviesky.info/$1 [L,R=301]
```

That should give you the desired results.

Comment: Hii, Open Source Training Rajkot.     Thanks for your answer, but I have tried to forward request using Cloudflare itself. And it' s working fine.   So should I continue using Cloudflare redirect??? Please Reply

Comment: Well, if the Cloudflare redirect produces the desired results, by all means you can continue using it.

Comment: you was right. Cloudflare is not producing desired results. So can u tell me that how can I redirect all results from moviesky.in (both http and https non-www and www) and results from moviesky.info (both http non- www and www and https - www to only https://moviesky.info)

So I am telling you that destination should be https://moviesky.info.

Pls reply with suitable answer.

Comment: Hii, there is one problem I dont know how, but http request from my site are automatically getting redirected to https

Comment: @Ujjwal As per your original question, I thought you wanted to redirect all http requests to https and as per your last comment, that is exactly what is happening, so I fail to understand your problem at this point.

Comment: I wanna redirect all http and https request from One domain to another domain. I mean one domain' s all request should permanent 301 redirect to another domain's https version!